# Using react-use-websocket inside of a Web Worker (Comlink)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket, web-worker

I have a websocket that sends and receives data and I want it to be running in a different thread. The thing is, I'm using react-use-websocket which is a react custom hook and I need to run that in a worker thread.

Is it possible to workerize a custom hook in React? I tried to implement it with comlink with no luck.

Comment: worker lives in different world than React/DOM. Why do you want to use a hook in the worker? what do you want to achieve?